# Unable to Publish my ElectronJS app to Microsoft Store

Tags: deployment, electron, desktop-application, microsoft-store

Unable to Publish my Electron JS app to Microsoft Store even in Note certificates I have provided them with the packages that my app is using. Here are the packages that I am using :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "auto-launch": "^5.0.5",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
    "deasync": "^0.1.28",
    "electron-dl": "^3.5.0",
    "ffi-napi": "^4.0.3",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "fswin": "^3.23.119",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "node-gyp": "^9.4.0",
    "ref-napi": "^3.0.3",
    "sharp": "^0.32.3"
  }
```

In Microsoft store there is only 2 options to publish my electron app that i can see .exe or .msi so I gave them .exe package with all the signed certificates in it and silent install commands that while testing also passed the Package Validation check.

[Available Package Options in Microsoft Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOQOD.png)

Here the package validation check result

[Package Validation Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo7Q9.png)

Online wherever I am reading people all of the blogs are using electron-window-store package but while publishing there is no .appX format to be provded while publishing so didnt used that.

Please help me with this issue I will be very grateful if anyone help me regarding it. This is the report that they always reply with:

`10.2.4.2 Security - Software Dependencies -> Your product contains drivers that have not been provided by Microsoft.`

Trying to Publish my Desktop App in Microsoft store but it's always getting rejected.